# How do I debug the "Model <...> has more than one SearchIndex handling it" error in Django-Haystack?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I get the following error and I have literally no idea where to start. I have read that it could be threading or something else, but in my code there is only one occurrence of `DocumentIndex` which has a `document` as a model, nothing inherits it and the declaration is:

```
class DocumentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
```

The error is:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Model '<class 'documents.models.Document'>' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` handling it. Please exclude either '<documents.search_indexes.DocumentIndex object at 0x8363a78>' or '<documents.search_indexes.DocumentIndex object at 0x83b1870>' using the 'EXCLUDED_INDEXES' setting defined in 'settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS'.
```

Comment: full `class DocumentIndex` plz

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a racing condition occurring in UnifiedIndex class of haystack.utils. It is supposed to be solved in django-haystack 2.4.

You can read all about it [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/615).

Try using search_view_factory as it thread-safe unlike the traditional SearchView.

Comment: It was apparently not fixed until version 2.5.1. See https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/commit/4e1e2e1c5df1ed1c5432b9d26fcb9dc1abab71f4